# query logic solution

Tags: mysql, sql

i have `table master: barang` and `table view: v_barang`
and i have this query:

```
SELECT v_barang.part_number , barang.total FROM v_barangINNER JOIN barang WHERE v_barang.id_item = barang.id_item
```

but before the query displays the results i want to check from table `barang`
`if stock.barang >= 1` displaying query, else don't display.

Comment: you can add it at where condition

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXISTS :

```
select * from v_barang where id_kategori = 2 
                AND exists(select * from barang where stock.barang >= 1)
```

`Exists` ensure that subquery returns some record and if no record returned from subquery, then there would be no result with whole query.

Based on OP comment query, you can do like this :

```
SELECT v_barang.part_number , barang.total FROM v_barang 
     INNER JOIN barang ON v_barang.id_item = barang.id_item WHERE barang.total >= 1
```

Comment: not work sir, i have this query SELECT v_barang.part_number , barang.total FROM v_barangINNER JOIN barang WHERE v_barang.id_item = barang.id_item.
and then i want to selection in table barang where total >= 1

Comment: I've updated query and you can check with latest one

Answer (score 0):

check the number of row with 
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_barang WHERE id_kategori = 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v_barang.part_number , barang.total FROM v_barang 
INNER JOIN 
barang WHERE v_barang.id_item = barang.id_item
AND
stock.barang >= 1;
```